# Delete data from API with Axios and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am fetching data from the jsonplaceholder API into my state. How can I remove the data with the `deleteContact()` method? My greatest struggle is how to get the `deleteContact()` method right.

Is this approach wrong?

```js
class RemoveFromAPI extends Component {

    state = {
        users: []

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
            .then(res => {
                const users = res.data;
                this.setState({ users });
            })
    }

    deleteContact () {
        axios.delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`);
        .then(res => {
            const users = res.data;
            this.setState({ users });
        })

    }

    render() {

        const {users} = this.state

        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    { this.state.users.map(user => <li>{user.name}</li>)}
                </ul>

                <button
                    onClick={deleteContact}
                   >
                    Remove
                </button>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

RemoveFromAPI.propTypes = {};

export default RemoveFromAPI;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you mean that you want to remove the user from the state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things to revise here - first, it seems you need to pass the `user.id` to the `deleteContact()` function, given that your axios request requires the user id as part of the request URL. This typically means moving the "Remove" button into the `map()` render callback so that each user id can be passed through the buttons click handler:

```
render() {

    const {users} = this.state

    return (<div>
            <ul>
            { 
              this.state.users.map(user => (
              <li>{user.name}
                  <button onClick={ () => this.deleteContact(user.id) } >Remove</button>
              </li>))
            }
            </ul>
        </div>);
}
```

Also, note the use of the "arrow function" passed on `onClick`:

```
() => this.deleteContact(user.id)
```

Arrow functions provide a convenient way to call a class methods that are bound to the current component instance. This is important to ensure methods like `setState()` work as expected from inside the class method being called.

Finally, the `deleteContact()` method itself needs some minor revisions. Ensure the `id` parameter is declared as a function argument and also remove the `;` following your `axios.delete()` to avoid a syntax error, like so:

```
deleteContact (id) { // <-- declare id parameter
    axios.delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`) // <-- remove ;
    .then(res => {
        const users = res.data;
        this.setState({ users });
    })
}
```

Hope that helps!

#### Update

Another note; your code is expecting the API at `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/` to return list of items after a `DELETE` request according to the documentation this doesnt seem to be the API's behavior. One way to address this would be to update `deleteContact()` to first issue the `DELETE` request, followed by a `GET` request like so:

```
deleteContact (id) {

    // Issue DELETE request
    axios.delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
    .then(() => {

        // Issue GET request after item deleted to get updated list
        // that excludes user of id
        return axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    })
    .then(res => {

        // Update users in state as per-usual
        const users = res.data;
        this.setState({ users });
    })
}
```

Note also, this placeholder API [does not actually remove data from the server](https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder#deleting-a-resource) which will mean the delete operation will appear to have no effect.

Comment: Thank you!  Getting this error: TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function

Comment: You're welcome :) are you seeing this error immediately, or after clicking the Remove button?

Comment: After clicking  the Remove Button

Comment: From the documentation it appears that `delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)` does not return a list of users (as your code expects) - one option is to issue the "delete" request and follow that by a "list query". Did you want me to update the code to show this?

Comment: Yes please,  that would be really nice!

Comment: Hi,  I'm Getting this error  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error and Undefined